# c++ space problem

Tags: c++

Why wont this command work if it has space in it?

I wanna use this like `alani hur up` and `alani hur down` but it dont work, i tried renaming the command to `alanihur` just to see if its some other problem but it worked then i did that so.

Why cant i have space?

blabla.h

```
bool Levitate(Creature* creature, const std::string& cmd, const std::string& param);
```

blabla.cpp

```
{"alani hur",&Commands::Levitate}


bool Commands::Levitate(Creature* creature, const std::string &cmd, const std::string &param)
{

 if(param == "up"){
     Position newPos = creature->getPosition();
     newPos.z--;
     if(g_game.internalTeleport(creature, newPos) == RET_NOERROR){
        g_game.addMagicEffect(newPos, NM_ME_ENERGY_AREA);       
    return true;
    }
 }
 else if(param == "down"){
                  Position newPos = creature->getPosition();
newPos.z++;
Tile* tile = g_game.getTile(newPos.x, newPos.y, newPos.z);      
if(tile && tile->creatures.size() != 0){
    newPos.x++;
}

if(g_game.internalTeleport(creature, newPos) == RET_NOERROR){
        g_game.addMagicEffect(newPos, NM_ME_ENERGY_AREA);

    return true;
}

 }

 return false;
}
```

Thanks alot and exuse my kind off poor english

Comment: The code you posted seems to be completely unrelated to what you are asking. Please post relevant code.

Comment: The code is quite relevant! May I know what part you found irrelevant?

Answer (score 1):

If your program uses the tokens system to parse the command, and considers space as a delimiter, that would be one explanation why spaces have that effect.

Answer (score 1):

The command is parsed as a String, and then, the space makes quite some difference. You must understand this, given you are working on this type of a program.

If you need to absolutely separate the words alani and hur, you can add an underscore to make it look like alani_hur.